# Core Data Annotation - Repairing Missing Delete Propagation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have a program that works perfectly fine. No crash, no bug or anything, but when it comes to deleting an NSManagedObject, the following message appears in the console.

```
Core Data: annotation: repairing missing delete propagation for to-one relationship
```

And then, some details about the relationship.

Once again, this does not make the app crash and the program goes on running as expected, but still, that makes me worried. Should I do something about it or is it alright to have some annotations from Core Data?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Same thing is happening to me, are you using nested contexts?

Comment: No, just the regular Core Data stack.

Answer (score 7):

You should adopt a better strategy on deletion.

1. Go to your .xcdatamodeld, select the concerned relationship
2. Select your entity and relationship using an inverse relation
3. Choose what to do on Delete Rule

   [image]

Answer (score 5):

You must save context after deleting a managed object.

After deleting something:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSError *error;
if (![appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error in Appdelegate>getLocalVersionAddFirstVersion");
}
```

> Just as a new object is not saved to the store until the context is
>   saved, a deleted object is not removed from the store until the
>   context is saved. ([Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html))

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and it went away, as soon as i added an **inverse relationship** for the relationship in question.

Comment: This solved the problem for me as well. Any idea why?

Comment: No. I can only quote the Core Data Programming guide that says on several occasions that **inverse relationships** are very important to set: _"The most important features with respect to object graph integrity, however, are the inverse relationship and the delete rule."_, _"You should typically model relationships in both directions, and specify the inverse relationships appropriately."_

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a slightly different problem: there was an **orphan detection** in place that removed the newly created object right away when it was saved, because I forgot to add the new parent relationship to the `isOrphan()` function. Strangely enough it lead to exactly this error ...